# Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'

Tags: reactjs, node.js, compiler-errors, runtime-error, chokidar

I keep getting this error too often. I cannot work efficiently anymore as it happens every 15 seconds.

Does anyone have the same problem?
It started happening a few weeks ago.
I've tried everything that I saw on the internet.

- Disabling anti-virus
- Removing the npm cache
- Tried different browsers
- Other terminals + run as administrator
- Remove node_modules
- Update deps

and much more..

node:events:492
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
at FSWatcher._handleError (C:\Users<project_path>\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:647:10)
at NodeFsHandler._boundHandleError (C:\Users<project_path>\node_modules\chokidar\lib\nodefs-handler.js:303:43)
at ReaddirpStream.emit (node:events:514:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
errno: -4082,
code: 'EBUSY',
syscall: 'lstat',
path: 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
}

Note React v18 project